# How to get array type parameters

Tags: arrays, types, julia

In Julia, if I make `x = rand(10,2)`, then

```
>> typeof(x)
Matrix{Float64} (alias for Array{Float64, 2})
```

How do I access the type parameters, i.e., how do I obtain that the array `x` is an array of `Float64` and `2`?

Comment: You may want to edit the title of your question as you are not looking for a subtype but for type parameters or element type (as per the first line of the answer from DNF).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(BTW: You are not looking for a 'subtype', as your title says, but for 'type parameters'.)

The element type is easy to get with `eltype`:

```
jl> eltype(x)
Float64
```

The dimensionality can be retrieved from the `size` of the array:

```
jl> length(size(x))
2
```

Edit: Better to use `ndims`:

```
jl> ndims(x)
    2
```

If you don't have access to `x` itself, but only its type, `eltype` still works:

```
jl> T = typeof(x);

jl> eltype(T)
Float64
```

The dimensionality is a bit more difficult. You can inspect the properties of the type variable (but I don't recommend that, since this is an internal implementation detail of the type, and may not be stable):

```
jl> T.parameters
svec(Float64, 2)

jl> T.parameters[2]
```

A better way is probably to make a function to get this for you:

```
jl> dims(::Type{<:AbstractArray{T, N}}) where {T, N} = N
dims (generic function with 3 methods)

jl> dims(T)
2
```

**Edit:** You can use `ndims` with type variables too:

```
jl> ndims(T)
2
```

So, actually, the answer is: `eltype` for the element type, and `ndims` for the dimensionality, both when you have an array and when you have the type of an array.